# Group all rows with same values but concat unique values, many to many relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table `user`:

```
id | name
1  ,  Mark
```

and table `specialization`

```
id | spec
1  ,  addictions
2  ,  psycho
```

and this table connecting user and specialization: `user_specialization`

```
user | specialization
1    ,        1
1    ,        2
```

I want to get the list of all users and their specializations
`Mark, specialization: addiction, psycho`

I also want to get those users that dont have any specializations

I have this SQL

```sql
SELECT name, spec 
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN user_specialization ON user.id = user_specialization.user 
LEFT JOIN specialization ON user.specialization.specialization = specialization.id
```

And this gives me this result

```
name | spec
Mark , addictions
Mark , psycho
```

I need this:

```
name | spec
Mark | addictions, psycho
```

How can I acheive that? I suppose that i will need `GROUP BY name` but i dont know how to concat those `spec` rows.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group_concat as follows:

```
SELECT name, group_concat(spec)
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN user_specialization ON user.id = user_specialization.user 
LEFT JOIN specialization ON user.specialization.specialization = specialization.id
Group by name
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! It look like this "addictions,psycho" and i wonder is it possible to add space after comma? So it would be "addictions, psycho"